# SnakeYaml, read into the class all under particular tag, ignoring everything else

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I have some YAML file containing lots of configurations but I need the only one tag (**mytag**) from that.

```
component:
  field1:
    - name: nnn1
  field2:
    - name: mmm1

mytag:
   description: hello
   mycomponents:
      - propertyA: aaa
        propertyB: bbb

theirtag:
   bbb: 111
   comps:
      - propA: aaa
        prop: bbb
```

I need to load:

```
class MyClass {
   String description;
   List<MyComponent> mycomponents:
}
```

How to do that with **SnakeYaml** ?
I have not been able to quickly find any useful example.

Follow up: what to do if my tag is nested more **deeply**: (boo / mytag)

```
boo:
  mytag:
    description: hello
    mycomponents:
      - propertyA: aaa
        propertyB: bbb
```

Thanks !

Comment: How would the relevant data be identified? According to the follow up, you want to do something like „load the part of the data that is nested under a `mytag` key anywhere in the YAML file“, is that correct? Also please don't use the word tag, a tag in YAML is something like `!!str`.

Comment: >load the part of the data that is nested under a mytag key anywhere in the YAML file“, is that correct?
exactly, I need to load the class from some prefix, like 'boo/mytag'

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial. While it may be doable using custom constructors, their interface is quite hard to handle for cases like this and I am not certain how to do it.

Instead, you can override the default parser behavior and just throw away any events around the `mytag` key, so that the event stream the parser emits only consists of the events inside the value of the `mytag` key. Here's a minimal working example:

```java
package droggeljug;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.events.*;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static class MyParser extends ParserImpl {
        private final String containingKey;

        private int depth = -1;
        private boolean checked = false;

        public MyParser(StreamReader reader, boolean emitComments, String containingKey) {
            super(reader, emitComments);
            this.containingKey = containingKey;
        }

        @Override
        public Event peekEvent() {
            if (checked) return super.peekEvent();
            Event e;
            while (true) {
                boolean seenContainingKey = false;
                e = super.peekEvent();
                switch (e.getEventId()) {
                    case StreamStart:
                    case DocumentStart:
                    case Comment:
                    case StreamEnd:
                    case DocumentEnd:
                        return e;
                    case Scalar:
                        if (depth == -1) {
                            if (containingKey.equals(((ScalarEvent)e).getValue())) {
                                seenContainingKey = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    case Alias:
                        break;
                    case MappingStart:
                    case SequenceStart:
                        if (depth > -1) {
                            depth++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case MappingEnd:
                    case SequenceEnd:
                        if (depth > -1) {
                            depth--;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                if (seenContainingKey) {
                    depth = 0;
                } else if (depth > -1) break;
                checked = true; super.getEvent(); checked = false; // discard
            }

            if (depth == 0) depth = -1;
            checked = true;
            return e;
        }

        public Event getEvent() {
            Event ret = super.getEvent();
            checked = false;
            return ret;
        }
    }

    public static class MyYaml extends Yaml {
        private Object loadContainedFromReader(StreamReader sreader, Class<?> type, String containingKey) {
            Composer composer = new Composer(new MyParser(sreader,
                    loadingConfig.isProcessComments(), containingKey), resolver, loadingConfig);
            constructor.setComposer(composer);
            return constructor.getSingleData(type);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public <T> T loadContainedAs(Reader io, Class<T> type, String containingKey) {
            return (T) loadContainedFromReader(new StreamReader(io), type, containingKey);
        }
    }

    public static class MyClass {
        public static class MyComponent {
            public String propertyA, propertyB;
        }

        public String description;
        public List<MyComponent> mycomponents;
    }

    private static final String input =
            "component:\n" +
            "field1:\n" +
            "  - name: nnn1\n" +
            "field2:\n" +
            "  - name: mmm1\n" +
            "mytag:\n" +
            "    description: hello\n" +
            "    mycomponents:\n" +
            "      - propertyA: aaa\n" +
            "        propertyB: bbb\n" +
            "theirtag:\n" +
            "    bbb: 111\n" +
            "    comps:\n" +
            "      - propA: aaa\n" +
            "        prop: bbb\n";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyYaml yaml = new MyYaml();
        MyClass data = yaml.loadContainedAs(new StringReader(input), MyClass.class, "mytag");
        System.out.println("description = " + data.description);
        for (MyClass.MyComponent c : data.mycomponents) {
            System.out.println("component: (" + c.propertyA + ", " + c.propertyB + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

The filtering code is not completely correct and fails for example if `mytag` is a value or a sequence item somewhere. You'd need track the parser state to ensure the current Scalar is a mapping key. I didn't implement that because the code is long enough as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple, just do:

```java
class MyDoc {
   MyClass mytag;
}

class MyClass {
   String description;
   List<MyComponent> mycomponents:
}
```

Then load with your own Representer, as in...

```java
class SomeParser {
    private Yaml snakeyaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(MyDoc.class, getLoaderOptions()), getMyRepresenter());

    private static Representer getMyRepresenter() {
        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
        Representer representer = new Representer(options);
        // we aren't that strict
        representer.getPropertyUtils().setSkipMissingProperties(true);
        return representer;
    }

    ...
}
```

Doing this you'll just *drop* every other field you don't care about.

If you want the entrypoint to be a dynamic *key*, not depth, you should be able to use a custom `TypeDescription` on for `MyDoc` to map it:

```java
class SomeParser {
    private Yaml snakeyaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(getDescriptor(), getLoaderOptions(), null, getMyRepresenter());

    private static TypeDescription getDescriptor() {
        TypeDescription myDesc = new TypeDescription(MyDoc.class);
        myDesc.substituteProperty("notmytag", MyClass.class, "getMyTag", "setMyTag");
        return myDesc
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want a dynamic depth, I *think* you may be able to create a custom Constructor which inspects the value and walks down based on value name, but I'd need to test that.