# How to read a Iterable nested object - Java

Tags: java, yaml

Hi all I have the following yaml file example 'test.yml'

```yaml
server:
  port: 1000
  someDate: /abcd

anotherConfig:
  host: http://localhost:1000

fileList:
  files:
    - name: filea
      filePath: \filea
    - name: fileb
      filePath: \fileb
---
anotherdoc:
  data: 300

nestedData:
  animal:
    - name: dog
```

I read this file like so:

```java
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.yml");

Iterable<Object> rules = yaml.loadAll(inputStream);
for (Object rule : rules) {
  Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) rule;
  System.out.println("blah");
}
```

I am wondering how it is possible to get data from the rules object, e.g. if I wanted directly to search `fileList/files` or `nestedData/animal` so that I can use the path to get a List directly.

(Note yaml structure varies so cannot seem to use the entities method)

Answer (score 0):

`fileList/files` is not a path in YAML terms because the YAML spec does not define any kind of *path*. You can:

1. use `composeAll` to get an iterator on `Node`s. Nodes represent the YAML's structure and you can navigate through them similar to an XML DOM. You can then write a function that can walk a path.
2. plug in a modified parser that throws away everything not on your desired path, so that only your path is constructed. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67645161/347964) shows the basics for a slightly different use-case.
3. Write a custom constructor that throws away everything around the desired path. I am not entirely sure whether this is possible because the constructor API is a bit strange.

I suggest using method 1. It is flexible enough to deal with any kind of YAML structure, while being far less complex than the other methods. When you arrive at your desired `Node`, you can even use the `Constructor` class to construct a `List` or whatever you need from it.